# Replace feature values from one field to another

Tags: qgis, sql, expression

I want to replace those values within the field `Type` that has these specific values: `MLW` and `MHW` with those values that are in the same row as this within another field.

How would I do this? for example:

```
Type    Type2
Field    Field
Field    NULL
Park     Park
Park     NULL
MHW      Park
MLW      Field
```

To this:

```
Type    Type2
Field    Field
Field    NULL
Park     Park
Park     NULL
Park     Park
Field    Field
```

`MLW` or `MWH` is always followed by a value in `Type2` and never `NULL`

Comment: Update your "type" field with `Type2`. This replaces all values in "type" with those in "type2".

Comment: @Erik I have noticed that your suggestion would not work and I have updated as to why. I should have presented this at first but this is what my dataset looks like as far as I am aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SE GIS!  Here's one way to solve your problem:

1. Open the attribute table and start editing.
2. Click the *Select features using an expression* button.  This will open up the *Select by expression* window.
3. In the left pane enter the expression **"Type" = 'MLS' or "Type" = 'MHW'**  (Note the double and single quotes).  Click the *Select features* button, and then the *Close* button. This will select only those records that you wish to alter.
4. Click the *Open field calculator* button, which opens the *Field Calculator* window, as shown below.
5. Check *Update existing field* and drop-down to **Type**.  In the left pane enter **"Type2"**
6. Voila! **Type** has now been updated to **Type2**, but only for the selected records.
7. Save your edits and stop editing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is far more efficient than the approach I was using. I created a new field while running this `if else` statement: ```if("Type" is 'MWH', "Type2", "Type")``` then repeating. However, I reckon that I could index both within the `if` statement like you did in the expression, would that work? i.e. ```if("Type" is 'MWH' or "Type" is 'MLW', "Type2", "Type")```?

Comment: Did you try your improved if() statement?  What were the results?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in the field calculator in a single operation using a regex search and replace:

`regexp_replace("Type",'MHW|MLW',coalesce("Type2",''))`

`"Type"`: look at the field Type.
`'MHW|MLW'`: search for text MHV or (`|`) MLW.
`coalesce("Type2",'')`: replace by the value of the field `Type2`, or an empty string if it is null. (note that if you omit this, the output would be Null each time `type2` is null, regardless of the value of `type`.

Comment: I like this method! I watched a video before seeing this on the `coalesce` function which makes that line of code appear to me in perfect sense! I will look to implement code similar to this. THanks!